# pass by reference, address of the reference remains unchanged

Tags: c, pointers

I have a program below:

Here I have a function called `test()` which takes address of a pointer tree1, I am trying to update the address of pointer `*tree1` after the `test()` is executed. I was hoping since `*tree` in `test(sample *tree)` is a refernce to `tree1` adress , if I update `tree1` , it also updates `tree`. oops!I know I got it wrong. So the goal of the program is to update the address of `*tree1` with address that has been placed in `*tree`,after `test()` is completed . Is there a way to accomplish this goal?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


typedef struct abc { 
        int num;        
    } sample;

sample *test(sample *tree){

    sample *text,*text1;

    text=(sample *)malloc(sizeof(sample));
    text->num=4;

    text1=(sample *)malloc(sizeof(sample));
    text1->num=6;

    tree=text1;

    printf("address of tree in test() is %p\n",tree);

    return text;

}

int main()
{

sample *tree1;

tree1=(sample *)malloc(sizeof(sample));
tree1->num=5;

printf("address of tree1 before test() is %p\n",tree1);

test(tree1);

printf("address of tree1 after test() is %p\n",tree1);

return(0);
}
```

Comment: Sorry , I am using C

Comment: Is there any pre-defined function I can leverage here?

Answer (score 1):

Pointers are copied when passed to a function, so changing the new pointer address does not affect the original pointer.

```
typedef struct abc { 
        int num;        
    } sample;



sample *test(sample **tree){

    *text=(sample *)malloc(sizeof(sample));    
    return *text;
}
```

Comment: Rather than giving direct answer, it is helpful to just show direction while learning.

Answer (score 1):

You only need a series of small change, and perhaps also add some null ptr tests. Because in `C` all param passing is by value, you have to pass to `test()` the *address* of `tree1` so that the function can plop some new value in that address. Something like,

```
sample* test(sample **ptr_to_tree) { // change defn
```

And then, update this pointer value, as

```
(*ptr_to_tree) = text1; // was tree=text1 changing what is basically "returned"
```

Finally, when invoking test() you need to pass address of tree

```
test(&tree); // changing how to use it
```

Comment: Is it possible not to change the signature and the way method is invoked in main(). I have test case which need to pass with out changing anything other than the content inside the function test(). There should be a way to do this with changes the skeleton of the code.

Comment: Function test() is returning two pieces of info - one via return value and another via updating an argument. However, your main code does not appear to interested in the return value. So yes you *could* work without change to input parameter and work simply via return value. `tree=test(tree)` and let `test` return `text1`. (Beware, your code has a few  memory leaks....)

Comment: Sorry for missing some information on return type. The return type has it own use in main() and can not be eliminated. I was interested in updating the argument's address only so I did not care about the return type of the function. Sorry . Is there any other work around. Appreciate your inputs here.

Comment: Hmm.. return value is already accounted for, must pass sample* as parameter, I am afraid I cannot think of anything else. In C++ you already have a good answer from someone that suggested passing a *reference* to the pointer -- but that will cause a change in function declaration from `sample* test(sample*tree)` to `sample* test(sample*& tree)`

Comment: Thanks, Do you know of any predefined function for this?

Comment: Is there any predefined function to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use double pointer. This would be good tutorial for you that what is the need of double pointer.

Comment: I have to keep the signature and invocation as same since it is a test case. I am hoping there should be a way to do this by changing only the content of test(sample *tree) function. Thanks